# file/folder properties very slow to open

Tags: windows, properties, directory

I have a little problem with my System.

Some time ago, when I left-clicked a file/folder, it was so slow to open the menu "open, open with.., rename etc".

I solved that by using ShellExView, removing some non-Microsoft entries.

Nothing changed since then. Yesterday I have a different but similar problem. Left-clicking is fastas usual, but if i click "properties" it takes about 1 minute or more to open it, both with folders and files. I tried to use "alt+enter" too, but the result is the same.

I tried again using ShellExView but there are only Microsoft entries... Do you have any suggests? Thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Today I have the same problem. "Properties" of the usual Windows folder (aka "Directory") takes about 1 minute or more to open (file's "properties" opens normally).

With the help of ShellExView I have found, that there exists association:
File Extensions = "Directory" with Extension Name = "IIS Shared Folder" (or something like that), so, when I deleted IIS, Windows folder's "properties" began to open almost instantly.

By the way, I notised in system log, that IIS had reported errors for some time, so it makes sense to check system events log.

Answer (score 0):

Check `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers` for extraneous entries and remove any that are unwelcome or unused. Uninstall corresponding programs with Add/Remove Programs.

Answer (score -1):

Just as a (very late) followup: meatspace's answer proved insightful on the current build of Windows 10. I had installed MountainDuck, which placed several unwanted ContextMenuHandlers in the registry. I used MountainDuck's own uninstaller to remove it and found a single entry left afterwards.